# Pspicture to Cover the Entire Page

Tags: xetex, geometry, books, dimensions, pspicture

I am working on a book whose geometrical page dimensions (W x H) are 4" x 6".

For one page, I would like to perfectly display a 4" x 6" `pspicture`.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=6in \textwidth=4in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.235} % 0, 107, 60
\psset{unit=1in}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,6)%

\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{red}%
\psframe[fillcolor=cadmiumgreen,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(4,6)%
\psframe[linecolor=cadmiumgreen](0,0)(4,6)% frame

\rput(0,5){PLACED AT (0,5)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In the case of the MWE, I am trying to code a 4" x 6" solid green page. However, (including the worded display at the point (0,5)), this is what is produced:

[image]

By the displayed note, ``PLACED AT (0,5)'', it seems that Latex has produced what it recognizes as a 4x6 green `pspicture`. However, there is much white space also displayed, which to me indicates that if the `pspicture` is 4x6, then the dimensions of the page are not 4x6, despite the commands, `\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry} \textheight=6in \textwidth=4in`.

I'm not sure what has caused all this.

QUESTION: Overall, how may I accomplish the following: (1) a page to be printed on 4" x 6" paper, with (2) a 4" x 6" `pspicture`that entirely covers the said page --- so that when I print the output on 4" x 6" paper, the page is entirely comprised of the said `pspicture`?

*Remarks:* The `pstricks` and `psvectorian` packages are included in the MWE because I may be using them in the actual `pspicture`. The code is compiled with `xelatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page size is defined by `geometry` and is exactly 4x6 inches as seen in the properties of the pdf file.

[image: b]

An easy way to place a 4x6 inch figure in the center of a 4x6 inch page is to use a `tikz` node.

Frame line color was set to red to verify the correct positioning.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=6in \textwidth=4in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}   

\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.235} % 0, 107, 60

\psset{unit=1in}

\usepackage{tikz} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\placecover}{% put the image in the center of the page <<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.center){\coverimg};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\coverimg}{% define the image <<<<<<<<<
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,6)%        
        \renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{red}%
        \psframe[fillcolor=cadmiumgreen,fillstyle=solid](0,0)(4,6)%
        \psframe[linecolor=red](0,0)(4,6)% frame changed <<<<<
    \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}       
    \placecover % place the image       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa for this very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does this satisfy

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=6in, paperwidth=4in, margin=0pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, pstricks}

\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.235}

\psset{unit=1in}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,6)
        
        \psframe[%
                        fillstyle=solid,
                        fillcolor=cadmiumgreen,
                        linewidth=2pt,
                        linecolor=red]
                        (0,0)(4,6)
        
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for this very nice alternative to Simon Dispa's answer.